# Laravel Homestead serve command not working after editing .bashrc

Tags: ubuntu, laravel

Hello I added an alias to `~/.bashrc` and running `source ~/.bashrc`. since then the serve command isn't working it says the command can't be found. 
Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Please post your .bashrc file so that we can try to see what the error is. Otherwise, we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out if you edited it from windows.  Happened to me and I had to fix it by running the bashrc file through the dos2unix command to fix the line endings from windows style to unix.